# Запретить отражение картинок

Tags: android, java, webview

Делаю вход в личный кабинет через WebView, доступа к странице, на которой находится личный кабинет, нет. Собственно, можно ли в WebView сделать так, чтобы он не отражал картинки?

И можно ли задать определённую ширину страницы, т.е. после входа кабинет примерно 800px шириной, можно ли сделать, чтобы страница отражалась без горизонтальной прокрутки или это всё нужно решать с помощью парсера?

**Обновление**

ок, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?

```
id=org.bms.handy&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm9yZy5ibXMuaGFuZHkiXQ
```

Вот смотрите, как, например, это приложение осуществляет вход в лк? Через парсер?

**Обновление 2**

Ну вот смотрите, картинки я скрыл

```
webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(false);
```

Подогнал под размер экрана, вот пытаюсь скрыть div

```
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                "document.getElementsByTagName('myDiv1')[0].style.display="none"; " +
                "})()");
```

но что-то не работает.

Comment: Это решается с помощью мобильной версии.

Comment: Мобильной версии сайта? А как мне её сделать, если у меня нет доступа к этому сайту?

Comment: Никак. Для решения вашей проблемы действительно нужна верстка сайта под мобильные устройства. Авторизация в мобильных приложениях обычно делается с помощью POST запросов, но для этого нужен соответствующий функционал на сервере.

Comment: Через запрос. На сервере есть метод для авторизации, который возвращает (скорее всего в виде json) авторизационный токен.

Comment: Обновил  ответ